# Fluid textboxes exceeding the container

Tags: css

I am using third party tool [jotForm] for creating forms on my wordpress website and I noticed in Firfox, all text boxes are coming inside the container wherease in chrome and IE they are exeeding. I applied 100% width on textboxes so that they could be adjustable in any resolution.

Here is the screenshot of different browsers
[image]

And here is the URL where you can see the form http://aite.com.sa/about/

Also, I injected custom css for my form

```
.form-textarea, .form-textbox {
    padding: 4px 0;
    border: solid 1px #AAA;
    outline: 0;
    font-size:12px !important;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
    width:100% !important;
    }
.form-textarea {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: verdana !important;
    }
input:hover, textarea:hover,
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    border-color: #C9C9C9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 0px 8px;
    }
.form-all{
    float:left;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    width:100% !important;
    }
.form-input { width: 100%  !important; }
.form-line-error {background:none repeat scroll 0 0;}
.form-error-message { display: none !important; }
.form-label-left {
    display:none;
    }
.form-validation-error {border: 1px solid #C85959 !important;}
.form-button-error { color: #C85959;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the padding from your list items and add it to your list since it is adding to the 100% width

```
.form-line {
    /* padding: 10px; remove this*/
}

.form-section, .form-section-closed {
    padding: 10px
}
```

Comment: Also I think you should know that in safari the form fields on focus are glitching. The red outline doesnt appear until you click in a new field, then the field before it highlights, and it does that continuously.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged CSS3, check out box-sizing:
http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

By default, the total width of an element consists of:

- given width (in your case 100% of the container)
- border (if your border is 1px, add 2px in total)
- padding

For example:

```
div {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

This div will be 12px wider then the container.
Add box-sizing to the CSS:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

If you provide box-sizing: border-box, the element width will be calculated differently, and will INCLUDE padding and the border. The total width of this second div will be 100%.

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/7gW3R/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is up a couple of levels in your markup.

The input is 100% of the width of your .form-input
Your .form-input is 100% of the width of your li.form-line
Your .form-line is wider than your form

Check this LI

```
<li class="form-line form-line-error" id="id_3">
</li>
```

And the styles

```
.form-line {
    clear: both;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 97%;
    width: -moz-available;
    position: relative;
}
```

Margin, border, and padding widths are normally *added* to your defined width, so width: 97% is getting added to 10px of padding on each side. Your li is too wide and its children are filling it.

Read up on the box-model. There's a property called "box-sizing" you might be able to use for a quick fix on newer browsers, but understanding the box model properly will save headaches in the long run.

[Here's the official box-model page from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html)

[Here's Chris Coyier's more readable version](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/)